# Is there a way to consistently identify a user's device in your application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have an app - 'MyApp' - is there a way to consistently get a device identifier string within 'MyApp'?

i.e. Any time a user uses 'MyApp' on a particular device, I could call the API and get back the same string all the time?

Comment: The closest you can get is probably https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49

Answer (score 0):

identifierForVendor will change between installs, best to use CFUUIDCreate.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UUID"] == nil) {
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));
    CFRelease(uuid);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uniqueIdentifier forKey:@"UUID"];
}
```

The above will survive app re-installs.

Comment: This does not identify the device. If you reset your device and reinstall the device, a new GUID will be created.

Comment: >The above will survive app re-installs.
But not the device wipe. It happens sometimes, though. I suppose, there's no way to get a really consistent device-specific ID now

Comment: You could build your own UDID from the device using the MAC address and such, but doing so is not in the spirit of Apple preventing use of UDID.Rather than swapping the UDID with the MAC address, what are your actual requirements. Do you really need a constant UDID?

Comment: I don't think in iOS 8 the MAC address is returned any more (or it returns the same one for everyone).

Answer (score 0):

Apple may reject your app for sending personally identifiable information. Use an advertising ID instead:

```
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>

// Advertising ID
ASIdentifierManager *adManager = [ASIdentifierManager sharedManager];
NSUUID *uuid = [adManager advertisingIdentifier];
NSString *stringRepresentation = uuid.UUIDString;
```

Just make sure you abide by Apple's guidelines for UDID usage, including restrictions for users that have checked 'Restrict Ad Tracking' in Settings.